# phantomjs version to make google webfonts work

Tags: phantomjs, google-webfonts

I am using phantomjs in my node application I download the package from https://www.npmjs.com/package/phantomjs (version 1.9.19). But google webfonts doesn't work. How can I specify using phantomjs (https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/releases) 2.0.0 to try to make google webfonts work?

Comment: What OS are you developing this for?

Comment: You probably have to wait before taking the screenshot, because those fonts are loaded after the page load. Webfonts work and it shouldn't have to make a difference where they come from.

Comment: linux. "statically-compiled binaries for Linux" isn't available for version 2.0.